# Split a list into sublist by a separator not by index in C#

Tags: c#

I read this question: [Split List into Sublists with LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419019/split-list-into-sublists-with-linq) but it not help me for the following problem.

I have the following list

```
18
0
abcde
678
-----
23
1
abcde

-----
66
4
3rwer
1
another item
```

How can I split this list into sublist by `-----` separator ?

Thanks

Comment: How many items do you expect to get back, three or four?

Comment: It is variable ... That's why I put `-----` separator. Now I expects to have 3 sublists.

Comment: @SnakeEyes: The point is that you've got a separator at the end... do you want the last returned element to be an empty list?

Comment: `Split` from moreLINQ is what you're looking for: https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/Split.cs

Comment: @JonSkeet: I removed last `-----` to avoid confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of an existing operator to do this in LINQ to Objects itself, more the [MoreLINQ project](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) has the [`Split`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/Split.cs) method, so you can use:

```
var sections = originalList.Split("-----");
```

That returns an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>` - if you need a list of lists, you could use:

```
var sections = originalList.Split("-----")
                           .Select(section => section.ToList())
                           .ToList();
```

MoreLINQ has a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) that you might wish to use for installation.

Comment: That [`Split`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/Split.cs) has a tiny mistake on line 179: `if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("separatorFunc");` probably should be `separatorFunc == null`.

Comment: @dbc: Yes, you're right. I'll fix that. Still, it works for other cases :)